# Should you remove MEX / WSDL on your production server?

Tags: web-services, wsdl, mex

While exploring google for information about MEX and WSDL I came across a few separate posts both on Stack Overflow and on the Microsoft social forums saying you should disable them on production servers but not saying why.

I want to keep them on so new customers can quickly get to work with our services, but I am wondering if I'm missing some security aspect to doing this.

What are the reasons it's recommended to switch it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the service.  If it's something you want anyone in the world to be able to call, then there's likely no harm to leaving the metadata available.

OTOH, if it's something like ProprietaryCustomerData.svc, then you'll likely want to turn off metadata and perhaps give some careful thought to whether it should be a public service in the first place.